# Entity Framework after save event

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is there a `SaveChanges` event that fires after changes are saved, but before the change tracker is updated?

I am using EF 6.

I need to perform a task whenever the status changes on a certain entity.

I have overridden `SaveChanges` to set this up. I can use `ChangeTracker` to tell what changes. When it's the correct entity with the correct change I fire of my code.

After the base `SaveChanges` is called, `ChangeTracker` no longer shows the entity as modified, so I need to do my task just before I save. However, there is a chance that `SaveChanges` will fail and I should not have done my task.

How can I hook into the `ChangeTracker` after the save, but before the model and `ChangeTracker` is updated?

Comment: Why not backing up in dictionnary all object states before savechanges and deal with that dictionary after?

Comment: That's what I have done but it seemed dirty.

Comment: Have you tried overwriting the save changes in the dbcontext class?

Answer (score 2):

Can you override the save changes method?

```
//you will use a different dbcontext name than faroutEntities5
public partial class faroutEntities5 : DbContext
{
    public faroutEntities5()
        : base("name=faroutEntities5")
    {
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        ChangeTracker.Entries()....

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    ...
```

Comment: This will not work because if `base.SaveChanges()` fails they should not have performed their change.